# Why's the Firefox Button gray?

Tags: firefox, themes

Shouldn't the orange color be the default for the Firefox Button on Linux as well? Ubuntu even has orange colored buttons in the default theme, but why's the Firefox button gray?

Comment: I would guess this is more a Mozilla/Firefox design decision, not something related to Ubuntu..

Comment: Firefox is patched for integration into Ubuntu, so why can't the button be patched as well. I've been wondering the same for `notify-osd` support as there's already an add-on out there and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Mozilla had decided to make the button grey on Linux. You can try this addon (not tested by me):
https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/themed-button-for-linux/

Comment: I will wait for it to progress from experimental before trying it out...